# Use ternary operator for visibility in Android MVVM databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I am facing issue with this code in my xml file with error:
msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. View is missing it.
I want to hide the layout on the basis of some condition.

```
<include
            layout="@layout/test_ui"
            android:visibility="@{(viewModel.valueFormat==001) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            bind:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to import it. Add

```
<import type="android.view.View"/>
```

in the data section. You could also add a BindingAdapter for it that takes a boolean and perform the same operation. E.g.

```
@BindingAdapter({"visibility"})
public static void setVisibility(View view, boolean visible) {
    view.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

and then you use it like :

```
visibility="@{viewModel.valueFormat==001}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I am aware of the binding adapter, but was trying to do this way.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `BindingConversion`:

```
@BindingConversion
fun convertBooleanToVisibility(visible: Boolean): Int {
   return if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

And then you can use simply
`android:visbility="@{booleanVariable}`

Comment: Of course, I somehow forgot to convert it :).. But I think it's understandable.